# Reversing a comparsion function result given it's function pointer

Tags: c, function-pointers

Before i get too far into it - this IS a part of some homework. However, I have given it my best attempt and cannot seem to figure out how this can be accomplished.

I am given a heap struct, which holds a pointer to a comparison function used to compare the heap's elements. However, in a specific instance, the values from the comparison function given (strcmp in the example) needs to be reversed. Instead of returning a negative number if `a<b`, the comparison function that is called by the heap needs to return a positive number.

I cannot modify any of the methods that use the heap struct, and cannot pass in a method that does the sort correctly. I can make another function and then give a pointer to that.

Comment: So, you have tried something. Good! What have you tried? How did this not work?

Comment: I suppose you can retrieve the heap's pointer to its original comparison function, or in some other way get at that function in a way that allows you to call it.  You know exactly how the return values of the function you want relate to those of the existing comparison function for any particular arguments.  Have you then considered writing the new function in terms of the old?

Comment: Note, by the way, that the structure of a heap is not separable from the comparison function used to build it.  Changing the comparison function of a heap necessarily involves re-building the heap using the new comparison function.

Comment: Does the heap maintenance functions allow you to pass some sort of "private data" pointer to the comparison function?

Comment: @MagnusHoff I had tried a lot of things previous to this, and upon going to type them up here realized why a lot of them were wrong. I'll edit some of the things I have tried and post them later as an edit to the question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The heap has only one pointer to a comparison function - it shouldn't know that there is such a thing as an old or new comparison function.

Comment: @pogo2065, the heap data structure doesn't need to know about old or new comparison function, but your program evidently *does* know, and the comparison function you want *can* know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a new function and instruct the heap to use it as the comparator. This new function needs access to the existing comparator pointer; it will use the existing pointer to call the original comparator, receive its return value, "invert" it and return the inverted result to its own caller (i.e. the heap).

For example, here is a function that returns random *odd* integers and is implemented in terms of one that returns totally random integers:

```
int totally_random() {
    return 4; // chosen by fair die roll
}

int (*pointer)();
pointer = totally_random;

int odd_random() {
    int result = *pointer(); // passed in through a global but alternatives exist
    return result & 1 ? result : result + 1; // if even, add one to make odd
}
```